# Order by highest value of two datetime fields from two different tables

Tags: mysql, phalcon

I am trying to get a list of all topics ordered by the highest value of two dates:

1. The date of the most recent post on the topic or
2. The date of the start of the topic

Both values are in different tables. I use the query in Phalcon and this one works, but doesn't do what I want it to do. It may be because I haven't specified that I want the date of the last post to count (maybe it is picking the first one, I am not sure)? I hope someone can help me to make this query work.

```
$phql = "SELECT    ForumTopic.*
        FROM      ForumTopic
        LEFT JOIN ForumTopicPost
        ON        ForumTopic.id = ForumTopicPost.topic_id 
        WHERE     ForumTopic.forum_id = ".$forum->id." 
        GROUP BY  ForumTopicPost.topic_id
        ORDER BY  GREATEST(
                            COALESCE(ForumTopic.created_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                            COALESCE(ForumTopicPost.created_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                            ) DESC";


$all_topics = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

Comment: Would you mind to setup SQLFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, with aliases to simplify understanding it:

```
SELECT ft.*
FROM ForumTopic ft LEFT JOIN
     ForumTopicPost ftp
     ON ft.id = ftp.topic_id 
WHERE ft.forum_id = ".$forum->id." 
GROUP BY  ftp.topic_id
ORDER BY  GREATEST(COALESCE(ft.created_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                   COALESCE(ftp.created_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                  ) DESC
```

What sticks out to me is the `GROUP BY`.  You have this with no aggregation functions, and no references to `ftp`.  I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT ft.*
FROM ForumTopic ft LEFT JOIN
     ForumTopicPost ftp
     ON ft.id = ftp.topic_id 
WHERE ft.forum_id = ".$forum->id." 
GROUP BY ft.topic_id
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(ft.created_at, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
                  COALESCE(MAX(ftp.created_at), '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                 ) DESC;
```

Note that in addition to the `MAX()` the `group by` also changed.  You want to aggregate by the id in the first table.  It might be `NULL` in the second table.